# How can I automatically paste text in Python?

Tags: python, automation, whatsapp, pyautogui

In Python, I've been working on a Spam Bot that could be used for WhatsApp. After I run the script, I head over to WhatsApp Web, select a contact and let the spamming happen. However, I realised that `pyautogui.typewrite` didn't work well for longer messages and took more time, which doesn't really satisfy the concept of quick spamming. So, I think that pasting the full message turns the process much faster, instead of typing the message letter by letter.

So, this is the initial code that worked all good and fine, but couldn't type fast:

```
import pyautogui as pt
import time

# Get the data for the spam
limit = input("Enter limit:")
message = input("Enter message:")

i = 0
time.sleep(5)

# loop until the limit is reached
while i < int(limit):
    pt.typewrite(message)
    pt.press("enter")
    i+=1
```

Then, I decided to change the code so that it pastes instead of typing. So, I changed the line where the message is received from `message = input("Enter message:")` to `clipboard.copy(input("Enter message:"))`. Then, I changed the part where the message is typed from `pt.typewrite(message)` to `pt.hotkey('command', 'v')`  which uses the Macbook keyboard shortcut Command + V for pasting copied text. I also tried using `clipboard.paste()` which didn't do anything. It didn't really work like expected. You can yourself try the code, for me it didn't work the way I wanted:

```
import pyautogui as pt
import time
import clipboard

# Get the data for the spam
limit = input("Enter limit:")
clipboard.copy(input("Enter message:"))

i = 0
time.sleep(5)

# loop until the limit is reached
while i < int(limit):
    pt.hotkey('command', 'v')
    pt.press("enter")
    i+=1
```

Comment: Do you know if the problem is with putting text on the clipboard, or getting the paste command recognized?

Comment: @MarkRansom the problem is with paste command. If I just had a program with the single line `clipboard.copy(input("Enter message:")))`and ran it, hitting Command + V manually afterwards would just paste the text I entered into the program, regardless of where I would paste it.

Comment: You can try using [pyclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyclip/) instead of clipboard.

Comment: @5rod pyclip will just do the same like clipboard or even pyperclip. It's paste command just gets whatever is in the clipboard but it won't control the keyboard and actually paste something wherever the mouse is...

Answer (score 0):

This is really complicated...but if clipboard isn't working, you can manually copy and paste the image, using `pyautogui`. (This is by NO means an efficient answer, but it's the best I could come up with).

Assuming you get the spam input from the shell of python, I found the ":" colon by using `pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen()`, to locate it in the shell. First, take a screenshot of the colon ":" in your python shell, and copy the path to the image.

Next, write this code:

```
import pyautogui

limit = input("Enter limit: ")

def get_cords():
    point = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("path to picture of colon")
    return (point.x, point.y)

copy = input("Enter message: ")
point = get_cords()
point = (point[0] + 16, point[1])
pyautogui.moveTo(point)
pyautogui.drag(50, 0, button='right')
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
#Copied text, paste wherever you need
```

And this might work, although probably not until you do a bit of tweaking. First of all, you need to get the path of the image of the colon in your python shell. Secondly, you need to measure the distance between the colon in the input text box. And there will probably be other tweaking. All of this...just to copy a simple word.

The way this works is pretty simple, but the code for it is much more complex than it really is. Normally, when a user copies text, they click and drag to highlight over the text, then copy it, usually with the keyboard shortcut ctrl+c/command+c. Here, pyautogui does it manually, but it is much more complicated, since we have to find the coordinates of the colon in the input box, and do a lot of clicking and dragging.

As you can see, this NOT efficient at all. Since `pyautogui` seems to be working for you, I suggest this. I do want to point out, for anybody who is looking at this answer, this is NOT a permanent solution. This is supposed to only be temporary, until you get the clipboard module stuff worked out.

Comment: your idea is really pretty creative and I wouldn't have come up with something this complex, but yet useful! It does fulfil the process of copying the entered text from the user, ready to get MANUALLY pasted. That part though was actually done already, so copying the text to clipboard with `clipboard.copy()`. However, the problem came up when we wanted to PASTE the text automatically in the message tab, where pyautogui.hotkey() didn't work. So, we only need to figure out how to paste the text, copying is already done. But still again, I really appreciate your idea and thinking!!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @SirArman. You should try using [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) instead, in that case, because keyboard allows multiple keys to be pressed, so it might be just what you need (sometimes pyautogui malfunctions).